# Rewriting a Java HttpURLConnection method using C# HttpClient

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient

I've got a working Java method that uses java.net.HttpURLConnection that I should re-implement in C# using the .NET HttpClient.

Java method:

```
public static String getMyThingAPIToken() throws IOException{
    URL apiURL = new URL("https://myThingAPI/token");
    HttpURLConnection apiConnection = (HttpURLConnection) apiURL.openConnection();
    apiConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
    apiConnection.setDoOutput(true);
    String apiBodyString = "myThingAPI login id and secret key";
    byte[] apiBody = apiBodyString.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

    OutputStream apiBodyStream = apiConnection.getOutputStream();
    apiBodyStream.write(apiBody);
    
    StringBuffer apiResponseBuffer;
    try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(apiConnection.getInputStream()))){
        String inputline;
        apiResponseBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        while((inputline = in.readLine()) != null) {
            apiResponseBuffer.append(inputline);
        }
    }
}
```

So far, my C# looks like below, and you'll notice that this early form of my implementation does not interpret the response.  Nor does it have a string return type required for the token string.

This is because when I test it, the response has:
StatusCode: 400
ReasonPhrase: 'Bad Request'

So something in my apiBody byte array or use of PostAsync must be different to what the Java method does, but I cannot work out what it could be.

```
public async static Task<HttpResponseMessage> getMyThingAPIToken(HttpClient client)
{
    var apiURI = new Uri("https://myThingAPI/token");
    string apiBodystring = "myThingAPI login id and secret key";
    byte[] apiBody = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(apiBodystring);
    var response = await client.PostAsync(apiURI, new ByteArrayContent(apiBody));
    return response;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried [StringContent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.stringcontent?view=net-5.0)? (Just a shot into the blue)

Comment: _"but I cannot work out what it could be"_ - use of a tool like FIddler or WireShark may be helpful to see differences in the requests on the line.

Comment: @Fildor yes, same result - seems like the API requires it to be a byte[].   But thanks,  I'll try the tools you mentioned

Comment: If you have access, server logs may also be helpful, if it writes something more detailed there.

Comment: None of the examples set content type explicitly, so that might be the difference too. But really as mentioned - just use the tool and inspect headers in both cases.

Comment: @trajekolus no API requires anything to be a `byte[]`, because *everything is always bytes*. Text is one way of interpreting those bytes. UTF8 is a specific way to encode text as bytes. If you use `StringContent` you say that you'll send a string and HttpClient will convert it to bytes using the specified encoding. What you do here is what `StringContent` would do

Comment: @trajekolus use a debugging proxy like Fiddler to see what, if anything, is different between the two requests. The Java code doesn't specify a `Content-Type` for example (which is weird), while HttpClient does. You don't need `Encoding.UTF8`, it's the default encoding for `StringContent`. In fact, [StringContent *is* a ByteArrayContent](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/57bfe474518ab5b7cfe6bf7424a79ce3af9d6657/src/libraries/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/StringContent.cs#L39) that does what you tried to do - encoding to bytes

Comment: @trajekolus what does the API really expect? The default for HttpURLConnection is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` - that's the content type for FORM POST. You can specify that in `StringContentType` as well, or use [FormUrlEncodedContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.formurlencodedcontent?view=net-5.0) to construct a proper FORM request. It's A LOT easier to find out how to do a specific thing like a FORM POST than trying to translate how another language does it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Java code doesn't specify a type which means that [by default](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14099_19/web.1012/b14020/HTTPClient/HttpURLConnection.html#getOutputStream__) the request uses `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. This is used for FORM POST requests.

The default content type for `ByteArrayContent` on the other hand is `application/octet-stream` while for `StringContent` it's `text/plain`.
FORM content is used through the [FormUrlEncoodedContent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.formurlencodedcontent?view=net-5.0) class which can accept any `Dictionary<string,string>` as payload.

The input in the question is *not* in a `x-www-form-urlencoded` form so either it's not the real content or the API is misusing content types.

Assuming the API accepts proper `x-www-form-urlencoded` content, the following should work:

```
var data=new Dictionary<string,string>{
    ["login"]=....,
    ["secret"]=.....,
    ["someOtherField"]=....
};
var content= new FormUrlEncodedContent(data);
var response=await client.PostAsync(apiURI,content);
```

To send any text using `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, we need to specify the content type in [StringContent's constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.stringcontent.-ctor?view=net-5.0#System_Net_Http_StringContent__ctor_System_String_System_Text_Encoding_System_String_):

```
var contentType="application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
var content= new StringContent(apiBodyString, Encoding.UTF8,contentType);
var response=await client.PostAsync(apiURI,content);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using following code:

```
                    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://myThingAPI/");
                    var message = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "/token");

                    // Add your login id and secret key here with the format you want to send
                    message.Content = new StringContent(string.Format("userName={0}&password={1}", UserName, Password));
                    var result = await client.SendAsync(message);
                    return result;
```